# Xamarin.Forms 'non breaking space' in localisation resource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, localization, resources

I would like to have a text defined in my resources which is not wrapped when rendered.

If I use the following code in xaml (hardcoded text) it works. But if I move the used text `Text="Premium&#160;Package"` to the resources, the text will be wrapped and the `& # 160 ;` will be used as a text!

How can I solve this?

Works:

```
   <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap" >
            <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.PremiumView_Description01}"  Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                        <Span Text=" " Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                        <Span Text="Premium&#160;Package" Style="{StaticResource BlueSmall }" />
                        <Span Text=" " Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.PremiumView_Description03}" Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                    </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
   </Label>
```

Does not work:

```
<Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap" >
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.PremiumView_Description01}"  Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                        <Span Text=" " Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.PremiumView_Description02}" Style="{StaticResource BlueSmall }" />
                        <Span Text=" " Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.PremiumView_Description03}" Style="{StaticResource BlackSmall}" />
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `Premium&#160;Package` in the `AppResources.resx` file, `&#160;` will not worked , it is by design.

If string in `AppResources.resx` file, it used for `Localization`, it will need to support diferent characters of various forms. whatever characters that you input the `AppResources.resx` file, it will output the same characters.

If you want to use achieve the Space effect, just input it in the `AppResources.resx` file.

[image]

Or add this `"Premium&#160;Package"` separately.

In the `AppResources.resx`.

[image]

In the xaml code like following code.

```
 <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextType="Html" >
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                   
                   
                    <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.String1}"  />
                    <Span Text="&#160;"  />
                    <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.String2}"  />
                   
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
```

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue